# Can I stick extra stuff in HTML tags so that my JQuery can pick up on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates

```
<div id="holder" rel="http://mysite.com/go.jpg" rel2="42pixels" rel3="gaga">
blah
</div>
```

Is this allowed?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Could it be done with [jQuery's data system?](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, I would recommend using [HTML5's custom data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) to achieve this:

```
<div id="holder" rel="http://mysite.com/go.jpg" data-rel2="42pixels" data-rel3="gaga">
    blah
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The common approach for this scenario is to employ the `data-*` [pseudo-namespace](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).

This doesn't validate in all version of HTML; but it's relatively innocuous and very handy; and a lot better than a lot of other approaches.

**Edit:** Examples are always great:

```
<!-- In an HTML file loaded with AJAX, for instance: -->
<ul>
  <li data-id="1">My Little Pony</li>
  <li data-id="2">Transformers</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data-*` attribute is the proper way to add custom attributes, but that is only valid in HTML5. Personally, I usually use either the `id` or the `class` attributes to pass extra data. In your case, you could even do something like:

```
<div id="holder" class="http://mysite.com/go.jpg_42pixels_gaga">blah</div>
```

and then use something along these lines to access that data:

```
var divParams = $("#holder").attr("class").split('_');
alert('Param 1 is: ' + divParams[0] + ' / Param 2 is: ' + divParams[1] + ' / Param 3 is: ' + divParams[2]);
```

Of course, you might want to use a more complex separator than the underscore to make sure you don't split the string wrong, I just used it as POC.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't validate that way: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/scripttriggers/

You could provide a custom DTD to make it "valid": http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customdtd/

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by "allowed". It'll work, but your validation will be shot. The `class` attribute was intended to cover these kind of extensions (though nobody really uses it for anythign but CSS, so it's arguably become *de facto* abusive to do so).

Comment: I had no idea this was the original intention of `class`. So if you wanted to store e.g. an image id of 42, the actual intention was that you should do `class="imageId42"` (or similar)? I find that quite awkward.

Comment: @Frode - it is quite awkward! Class was originally copncieved as away of extending data about the element. You'll run into a few JS applications which do this from tiem to time, but it runs against the principle of least astonishment now so it's frowned on.